# Text to 2D Char Array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to save a txt file in this format to a 2d array.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @@@ @ @ @@    @@
@ @ @@  @ @    @@ @@
@ @   @   @ @  @@  @
@ @@@ @ @   @@   @ @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

As of now, my code looks like this:

```
char maze[H][W];
int i;
char filename[100];

printf("Enter maze's filename: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
fread(maze, 1, sizeof(maze), fp);
for (i = 0; i < H; ++i) 
    maze[i][W] = 0;
```

H and W are defined as 6 and 20. When I print this using:

```
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<H; i++){
    for(j=0; j<W; j++){
        printf("%c", maze[i][j]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

I included `.txt` and this is what it prints.

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

    @@@ @ @ @@
@@
@ @ @@  @ @    @
@ @@
@ @   @   @ @
  @@  @
@ @@@ @ @
@@   @ @
@@@@@@@@@@
```

What do I need to change on my code?

Comment: Why don't you check that `fp` is not `NULL` after calling `fopen`?

Comment: Could you post the "gibberish" :)

Comment: I think `W` is  need to be  `21`.

Comment: Also note that `fread` is for reading binery data. The text file has at least some new-line characters if not trailing spaces, so it does not contain a valid binary representation of your maze. Consider reading lines with `fgets` and then populating your maze with the data you've read.

Comment: or 22 for the newline(s) (\r\n)

Comment: You should consider dynamic allocation, and maybe read your file line by line with fgets

Comment: Why are you asking for a filename without a `.txt` extension? Did you mean to add this back on again before attempting to open the file? (Perhaps you're reading the wrong file.)

Comment: I checked that `fp` is not `NULL` and it isn't. I tried changing `W` to `21` and it's still the same.

Comment: are you sure the maze you printf is the same maze you fread?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Only if the op intends to print it as a string. In the printing code posted, that is not the case.

Comment: Please check the return value of fread - which is the number of elements read.

Comment: I added a `.txt` when entering the file name and it looked much closer to the original though the spacing is different.

Comment: You might like to read this http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to learn on how to help yourself in such cases  the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define H 6
#define W 21 //change to 21, +1 for newline
```

....

```
char maze[H][W];
int i, j;
char filename[100];

printf("Enter maze's filename(w/o .txt): ");
scanf("%s", filename);
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
fread(maze, 1, sizeof(maze), fp);
for (i = 0; i < H; ++i) maze[i][W-1] = 0;

for(i=0; i<H; i++){
    printf("%s\n", maze[i]);//change
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file contains \r\n (windows style) newline, which is 2 characters. So you have to read 6*(20+2) characters but printf only 6*20 chars, if you keep it the way you coded it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to keep compatibility between a text format map and your maze you need to skip the final `\n` at the end of each line.

You can read a line at time and skip the newline.

The sample shows also the nature of array of arrrays that applies to **multidimensional arrays in C**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define H  6
#define W 20

void PrintMaze(char maze[H][W])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < H; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < W; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", maze[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char maze[H][W];
    int i;
    char filename[100];

    printf("Enter maze's filename: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    for (i = 0; i < H; ++i)
    {
        fread(maze[i], 1, W, fp);    //we use a single subscipt we get an array of W elements
        fgetc(fp);  //Skip '\n'
    }

    PrintMaze(maze);

    return 0;
}
```